# ECharts Punch Bar Scatter from dataset

Tags: echarts, apache-echarts

I'm trying to generate a Punch Card, but unlike the provided [example](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=scatter-punchCard), I'd like to use the `dataset` option.

Desired result: '*week*' (w1 .. w5) on xAxis and stacked (a1 .. a4) on yAxis, with *symbolSize* relative to respective value.

[image: punch bar]

I'm currently using these options. What am I missing?

```
{
"tooltip": {},
"dataset": {
    "source": [
    {"week": "w1", "a1": 1, "a2": 1, "a3": 1, "a4": 0},
    {"week": "w2", "a1": 3, "a2": 5, "a3": 2, "a4": 1},
    {"week": "w3", "a1": 2, "a2": 3, "a3": 1, "a4": 4},
    {"week": "w4", "a1": 6, "a2": 1, "a3": 2, "a4": 0},
    {"week": "w5", "a1": 6, "a2": 2, "a3": 3, "a4": 0}
    ],
    "dimensions": ["week","a1","a2","a3","a4"]
},
"xAxis": {
    "type": "category"
},
"yAxis": {
    "type": "category"
},
"series": [
    {
    "type": "scatter",
    symbolSize: function (val) {
        console.log(val)
        // how to use val / filter current category? (a1..a4?)
        return 10
    },
    }
]
};
```

See: [codepen](https://codepen.io/pax/pen/RwxzbGB)

Answer (score 0):

As for the size, you can see that `val` is simply an object and you can do something like this:

```
symbolSize: function (val) {
     return val.a1 * 10
  },
```

Comment: I feel the problem is earlier in the set-up, I can access values there, is just now `val` returns all the values from that week (a1..a4), I'd need just the corresponding value respective to the yAxis.

Comment: Ah okay, yes, you basically tried to create object that corresponds to multiple points. Take a look at this pen: 
https://codepen.io/rajniszp/pen/GRyVpNV 

Feel free to ask if you don't understand how it works